# LocatioManager issue

Tags: android, locationmanager

I developed an Android app that presents the current location of the device in the google map. Nothing new this far and everything worked perfectly at my ZTE Smart a7 (Android 2.3.2). But at my new device LG Maximo G (Android 4.1.2) the locations is not attained. In other words the LocationManager is always null. Anyone know why this is happening at this specific device/android OS version?

To start the listeners I'm using the following code

```
    public void startListeners() {

    //Test if locatioManager is null
    if( this.lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500L, 1F,this.currentListener);    
    }

    if( this.lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500L, 1F,this.currentListener);    
    }

    if(this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
        this.lastLocation = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    if(this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) != null) {

        if( this.lastLocation != null){

            if(  this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getAccuracy() > this.lastLocation.getAccuracy() ){
                this.lastLocation= this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }

        } else{
            this.lastLocation = this.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

    } 
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: I'm not sure why your new device isn't picking up your location but for future reference LocationManager is being deprecated. You might consider refactoring your code to use the new location apis https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a new device, have you tried going to Settings>Location> enable location from Wifi & Network? If this is the problem, you should always check to see if the user has it enabled, if they do not, you should take them to the settings menu so they can enable it.

Also, like Bobbake4 said, try to use the new LocationClient API.

Comment: That option is enabled, the application does not starts if that options is not enabled. But the return is null.